# Browse All Messages from WebSphere MQ at a single time using Java

Tags: ibm-mq

How can we browse all the messages in a WebSphere MQ queue in one API call using java?

Here is the code which I'm using.  Here I'm using this code a `for` loop until q depth is reached.

```
    MQGetMessageOptions gmo=new MQGetMessageOptions();
    gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT ;
    //System.out.println("Status: "+i);
    MQMessage out=new MQMessage(); 
    out.format =MQC.MQFMT_XMIT_Q_HEADER;//MQC.MQFMT_REF_MSG_HEADER; 
    mqCon.getQue().get(out,gmo);
    System.out.print(i);
```

How can I get all messages without using `for` loop? It's taking a long time to browse 10,000 messages.

Comment: how can i get all messages without using for loop. its taking long time to browse 10,000 messages

Comment: @Sheena, OP attempted to clarify the question in the comments and I edited the comment into the original post.

Answer (score 2):

*How can I get all messages without using for loop?*

Use a `while` loop.  Sorry, could not resist a slightly snarky answer on that one.  WMQ does not have an API call analogous to the SQL `select` statement.  Messaging and databases share some traits but address fundamentally different requirements.

*It's taking a long time to browse 10,000 messages.*

Take a look at the Performance SupportPacs.  These are published on the [SupportPacs main page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) and have names beginning with MP.  Find the one for your platform and MQ version and it will list different scenarios for putting and getting messages as well as performance tuning recommendations.

I would also ask why a normal app needs to browse 10,000 messages.  The QMgr will select messages for you based on MsgID, Correlation ID or property and this is *much* faster than browsing all the messages in order for the application to find the ones of interest.  Occasionally people need to browse all messages on a queue to archive the queue or to debug a problem, but this is the exception rather than the rule.  If a Production app regularly browses all messages on a queue, then the queues may have been inappropriately used as a database.

Answer (score 1):

*How can I get all messages without using for loop?*

```
MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
getOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT + MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
byte[] b = null;
while(true)
{
   try
   {
      queue.get(message, getOptions);
      b = new byte[message.getMessageLength()];
      message.readFully(b);
      System.out.println(new String(b));
      message.clearMessage();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
      break;
   }
   catch (MQException e)
   {
      if (e.completionCode == 2 && e.reasonCode == MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
        System.out.println("All messages read.");

      else
        System.out.println("MQException: Completion Code = " + e.completionCode + " : Reason Code = " + e.reasonCode);
      break;
   }
}
```

I have posted many Java/MQ samples here: 
http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_java.html

Comment: where do you define queue? What type of object is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just browse messeges (not retrive them), you can use javax.jms.QueueBrowser.
Is pretty fast...

```
import javax.jms.*   
...        
public ArrayList<Message> browse() {
...
QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser((javax.jms.Queue) lookupQueue());

Enumeration enums = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();

while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {

            Object objMsg = enums.nextElement();
            if (objMsg instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage message = (TextMessage) objMsg;

                Log4j.trace("Text message: " + i + ". MSG:" + message.getText() + " MSG id:"
                        + message.getJMSMessageID() + " MSG dest:" + message.getJMSDestination());

            } else if (objMsg instanceof ObjectMessage) {

                ObjectMessage message = (ObjectMessage) objMsg;

                Log4j.trace("Object Message: " + i + ". MSG" + " MSG id:" + message.getJMSMessageID()
                        + " MSG dest:" + message.getJMSDestination());

            }
        }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed the message format (out.Format) you are using. MQFMT_XMIT_Q_HEADER is used for messages that are sent to a transmit queue. Messages in transmit queue are not generally read by applications. MQ uses a transmit queue to send messages from one queue manager to another queue manager in a MQ network. I hope you are not browsing messages in a transmission queue.

For applications, message format would typically depend on the receiving application. For example if the receiving application is CICS based, then format would be MQFMT_CICS, for IMS it would be MQFMT_IMS. If text/string type of data is expected then you could use MQFMT_STRING. For administering MQ using PCF messages, then format can be MQFMT_PCF.